# Soap. XML example request in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

How to implement XML example request in PHP? I'm confused with arguments and sending WS url...

Example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="WS"> //here is my ws server URL
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:calculatePrice>
         <arg0 username="username" password="password">
            <calculationInput var1="xxx" var2="xxx"/>
         </arg0>
      </ws:calculatePrice>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried this, but it didn't work out.

```
<?php 

try{
    $soapclient = new SoapClient('WSDL'); //here is WSDL server

    $result = $soapclient->calculatePremiumRegistered(array(
        'arg0' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'), 
        array('calculationInput' => array('var1' => 'xxx', 'var2' => 'xxx'))
    ));

    print_r($result);

} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

How do I have to write those arguments correctly?
How to send WS server info?

Comment: "it didn't work out" does not provide any helpful information.

Comment: I just got error response that query is incorrect.